# Add buttons to a asp.net listview column for processing

Tags: asp.net

I want to add several buttons to a asp.net listview column for processing. Admin can dial members' phone number and then click on one of the 4 buttons to change the status of that member in db.

For example, there are 3 columns, memberid, phone and status.

memberid phone status

1 91234567 4 buttons to change the status after clicking them (4 status id:0,1,2,3)
2 95555555 4 buttons ...
3 95553155 4 buttons ...

I have already written a method to change the status:
public void changeStatus(int memberid, int status)

What is the code for those 4 buttons? set the command name and command argument? What's the server side event to process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the ItemCommand Event for what you want.

First add the buttons to your ListView Item Template

```
<asp:button runat="server" ID="button1" Text="Status 0" CommandName="Status0" CommandArgument="0" />
<asp:button runat="server" ID="button2" Text="Status 1" CommandName="Status1" CommandArgument="1" />
<asp:button runat="server" ID="button3" Text="Status 2" CommandName="Status2" CommandArgument="2" />
<asp:button runat="server" ID="button4" Text="Status 3" CommandName="Status3" CommandArgument="3" />
```

You can leave off the CommandName if you want.

Then in your code behind add the ItemCommand Event Handler

```
 protected void ListView1_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int status = System.Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

        switch (status)
        {
            case 0:
                //update status 0
                break;
            case 1:
                //update status 1
                break;
            case 2:
                //update status 2
                break;
            case 3:
                //update status 3
                break;
        }


    }
```